# Multisite different domains mapping error on GGS

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have setup a multisite WP 5.0.3 website on Google cloud. Which means no cPanel. 
Things are smoothly running. 
Current wp-config.php is like this:

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'something.net' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

But when I tried to point a domain to a new site following the instructions, the new domain does not display correctly, and give a website without a theme, as it seems. Also, when trying to go to newsite.com/wp-admin I get a redirection error.
This is a screenshot of the website: https://prnt.sc/mgt062
When checking solutions, there were instructions to add a cookie definition in wp-config.php .

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

I did that but then the following error started to appear:

> The constant "COOKIE_DOMAIN" is defined (probably in wp-config.php). Please remove or comment out that define() line.

Furthermore, the original website gave a white screen and stopped working until I removed the cookie definition in config file. 
DNS is updated successfully, and the new website is reached. 
I searched more, and found an advice to add the following code for cookies:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Same result as before. What am I missing?

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin 
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L] 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you are not able to access you admin dashboard for the new site, this couldbe due to several issue. what is your htaccess?  did you migrate your multisite installation from a localhost to you google cloud server?

Comment: Hello... No I have not migrated.

Comment: .htaccess: 
Hello... No I have not migrated. .htaccess is as follows:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: this is the htaccess to a single site installation, log into your network dashboard and go to Settings->Network Setup to copy the correct htaccess code.

Comment: True... Here is the code, which I copied to .htaccess after your note. Still same issue. I added the cookie line and got the cookie error again:
Looks better here: https://prnt.sc/mhrs5b 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: ok, that rules out the htaccess.  You seem to have some issues with you cookies too, did you setup [salt keys](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys) in your config file?  Also are you trying to set up a multisite with [multiple domains or multiple sub-domains](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Domain-based)? Note that this is only possible with a root installation

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, salt keys are set in wp-config file. 
I am trying to setup multi domains. The multisite is set to use subdomains and not folders. And it is a root installation. 
And whenever I try to add the Cookies definition in config file I get the Cookies error mentioned in the Question with an advice to remove that line.

Comment: Ok, now I understand a little more the issue. First of all, have you made sure that your sub-domain installation works?  You need to setup your child sites as subdomains before configure the top level domains for each.  Next you seem to be using both the [core WP 4.5+ multi-domain mapping mechanism](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping) as well as as the sunrise [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).  I would recommend you use only the built-in mechanism and remove the plugin.

Comment: Yes.. I activated the plugin to try it after the core did not work. Then I disabled it. 
The subdomain works fine, and can login to admin panel with no issues. 
When updating it to a domain, the admin panel is not accessible anymore.

Comment: Is your site running on https or http?  Can you inspect your page and open the 'Network' tab ([chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network) / [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) ) to see if your admin page is being redirected.

Comment: https .. and the setting in the site URL is https too. 
I did the inspection.. Shows many redirects for the admin page. But I could not understand much. Can I send you the url somehow?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add at the bottom the url + the network inspection results.  The redirects can come from either your htaccess file (but I [checked](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) that and it works), or from your server itself.  so it is likely the issue is with the server.  You an make a quick test by placing a simple `test.html` file in your root with 'Hello World' title and try to access the file from each of your domains and inspect your network each time to see if there are any redirects.

Comment: I tried removing the https from site settings, and things worked. 
So I think it is your note about SSL which can be configured incorrectly. 
You were right in the previous comment. And I thank you very much. 
I am using cloudflare's SSL and never had an issue with it, but it seems to be a problem in this case. Thanks again for going step by step until narrowing up the possible causes.

Comment: Now the admin login page appears, but it claims that the browser does not support cookies. ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Comment: Sure, glad we worked it out.

Comment: regarding cookies, you can set it up as per the codex instructions?  given that you had removed some settings in your config file.

Comment: Yes.. It gives this: The constant "COOKIE_DOMAIN" is defined (probably in wp-config.php). Please remove or comment out that define() line. 
I see those in config, however: /** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/tmp'); 
  Should the be here?

Comment: The SUNRISE constant is only required is you use the plugin, so you can remove that.  Check this [answer](https://community.bitnami.com/t/wp-multisite-multidomains-cookies-issue/46603/2) on multidomain cookie error.

Comment: Finally... Thanks for every piece of information you provided, they all helped. 
The final setup was: define subdomain to FALSE, and adding the cookies line in config. Also made sure the sunrise is removed. Thanks again for everything!!

Comment: Do you want to type up an answer and summarise your final solution, or shall I do it?  Its good to have a proper answer to make sure others can easily find the information

Comment: Good day.. Sorry I was traveling. If you do it it will be more accurate I believe...

Comment: Generally, there is a MUST HAVE plugin if you are using Cloudflare. It is Cloudflare Flexible SSL . A life savior for WP redirecting issue.

Comment: that's good to know.  I will type up our various points of discussion so it may help someone else!